# BTX loader manual

Tags: boot, freebsd, boot-loader

I Can't find any good manual/reference about BTX bootloader integrated into FreeBSD. 
Especially I would like to know:

- if it's functionality resembles GRUB 2. For example, if it can boot OS other  than FreeBSD
- how to edit it's boot menu, what options are available
- how to use it's command line ( I know there is help in command line, but it's very base )
- how to 'troubleshoot'

Do you know any good resources ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a pretty capable boot loader, but highly tailored around loading BSD kernels. Check out [this doc file](http://people.freebsd.org/~jhb/docs/loader.txt) for some general descriptions of the different features. The boot menu and options are well detailed in the [conf file man page](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=loader.conf&sektion=5). Command line usage and and general setup is covered in the main [loader man page](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=loader&sektion=8).